# d3 - how to format date on x-axis

Tags: d3.js

Super new to d3, and I apologize if this question is poorly worded.

I'm attempting to alter pre-existing code and reformat the dates that appear on the x-axis of my chart. Currently, my x-axis is showing a tick for each month, and the month is not abbreviated, e.g. *January*, *February*, etc.

For space-constraint reasons, I need to abbreviate these months, e.g. *Jan*, *Feb*, etc.

This is the code that creates the x-axis:

```
   master.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3axis.axisBottom()
        .scale(x));
```

I believe that I need to chain a function to the `axisBottom` call. I have been looking at `tickFormat` and `timeFormat` in the docs, and also at [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/0e276dc70bb9184727ee47d6dd06e915) example. I'm trying to do something like:

```
    master.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3axis.axisBottom()
        .tickFormat(d3axis.timeFormat("%m"))
        .scale(x));
```

but I get this error: *npmD3Axis.default.timeFormat is not a function*

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
axis.ticks(d3.time.months, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));
```

You have to change the formate form `%m` to `%b`

for d3.js v4

```
axis.ticks(d3.timeMonth, 1).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'));
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Also, I was using the wrong module. The correct module (for my setup) is `d3TimeFormat`, not `d3axis`. Thanks for your help and I'll accept your answer when SO lets me.

Comment: Please go ahead if it had your issue cleared. Also let me know if you need any help wrt this.